# I am trying to deploying to cloud function

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

When I am trying to deploy my project using firebase deploy.
I cause a deployment error.

my cloud function

```
const function = require("firebase-functions");

exports.hello = function.region("asia-east2").https.onRequest((req, 
res) => {
const message = req.query.message || req.body.message || "Hello 
World!";
res.status(200).send(message);
});
```

Error:

```
protoPayload: {
@type: "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog"
status: {
code: 3
message: "Build failed: Build error details not available. Please check the logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=cirrusly-d811c&advancedFilter=resource.type%3Dbuild%0Aresource.labels.build_id%3D8485e789-078b-4499-bf57-f1905d38c1c3%0AlogName%3Dprojects%2Fcirrusly-d811c%2Flogs%2Fcloudbuild"
}
authenticationInfo: {1}
serviceName: "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com"
methodName: "google.cloud.functions.v1.CloudFunctionsService.CreateFunction"
resourceName: "projects/cirrusly-d811c/locations/asia-east2/functions/hello"
}
```

My Logs

```
Deployment error.
Build failed: Build error details not available. Please check the logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=cirrusly-d811c&advancedFilter=resource.type%3Dbuild%0Aresource.labels.build_id%3D3bf8b169-4ea1-4aaa-84c9-ff01e67e7e33%0AlogName%3Dprojects%2Fcirrusly-d811c%2Flogs%2Fcloudbuild
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more details on how the cloud function looks, how you deploy it, and what is in the logs, as stated in the 'message' clause of your question, please?

Comment: I have added more information. Please review. Thanks

Comment: "Please check the logs at https://   " - and what is there?

Comment: The error message is the log data as mentioned above.

Comment: and above and below that line? any other messages/errors on how the deployment was going?

Comment: Can you please add to the case the way you deploy your cloud function and the logs from the https://. There should be logs regarding the reason why the build failed.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I found out the solution from firebase support. My node version is 15.8 but the cloud function supports the 14.5 version. Updating version worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the stable version of node.js v14.15.5. That worked for me.